# Save Array of objects into codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, codeigniter

I built a form where i have to create array of objects from kind of inputs related to each other like below:

```
{
 "name_node":{"type":"input","name":"name","validation":"required, alpha numeric"},
 "content":{"type":"textarea","name":"contentco","validation":"required, alpha numeric"}
}
```

I used Jquery to built this array then save it to an hidden input field named "inputs" in the form. so when i submit the form i could retrieve the object above like:

```
$this->input->post('inputs');
```

What i need to do is to save the previous object into the below format instead

```
[inputs] => Array(
                  [name_node] => Array(
                        [type] => input
                        [slug] => name_node
                        [name] => name
                        [validation] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => required
                                [1] => alpha numeric
                            )

                    )

                [content] => Array
                    (
                        [type] => textarea
                        [slug] => content
                        [name] => content
                        [validation] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => required
                                [1] => alpha numeric
                            )

                    )

            )
```

Comment: I guess "unserialize()" is what you're looking for. http://php.net/manual/de/function.unserialize.php

Comment: do you understand mechanic of models and all that? I can slightly feel that you are asking about either parsing (unserialize) data or actual "saving to database".

Comment: actually i am asking about parsing the object, I know how to save it to database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve in PHP by using [json_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and format your array using foreach loop like below.

```
$str = '{
"name_node":{"type":"input","name":"name","validation":"required, alpha numeric"},
"content":{"type":"textarea","name":"contentco","validation":"required, alpha numeric"}
}';

$arr = json_decode(($str), true);

foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
   $newArray[$k] = $v;
   $newArray[$k]['slug'] = $k;
   if(isset($v['validation'])) {
     $newArray[$k]['validation'] = explode(",",$v['validation']);
   }

}
print_r($newArray);
```

<kbd>[Working Demo](http://ideone.com/aijyOi)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
$inputs = json_decode($this->input->post('inputs'));
```

Now if you `print_r($inputs);` you will get bellow formation

```
 stdClass Object
    (
        [name_node] => stdClass Object
            (
                [type] => input
                [name] => name
                [validation] => required, alpha numeric
            )

        [content] => stdClass Object
            (
                [type] => textarea
                [name] => contentco
                [validation] => required, alpha numeric
            )

    )
```

If you want exactly structure then...

```
$inputs_object = json_decode($this->input->post('inputs'));

$data['inputs'] = array(
                        'name_node'=>(array)$inputs_object ->name_node,
                        'content'=>(array)$inputs_object ->content,
                    )

$data['inputs']['name_node']= explode(',',$data['inputs']['name_node']['validation']);
$data['inputs']['content']= explode(',',$data['inputs']['content']['validation'])
```

Comment: What if I have 100 key like `name_code` `content` then I need to write it for 100 key manually. :)

Comment: Hi @Roopendra I just write this code only for 1 key.. not for dynamic value.. if key is more than one then obviously use loop through the values and prepare it.. Your code is good.. When I post the answer I did'nt saw your answer otherwise I was not posting it.. :)

Comment: @SKG Thanks a lot for you cooperation